# what is non-standard about this package directory structure?

Tags: dart, dart-editor

I have the structure shown below. When I run dartdoc from the DartEditor and from the command line I get errors regarding "no such file" on an import. When I run my Dart app *bin/ebisu.ebisu.dart*, it works just fine. The dartdoc web page says you may need to specify package if your structure is non-standard. Mine must not be standard because if I add the --package-root flag that does allow me to generate documentation. I think it does look standard...what can I do fix the structure to make dartdoc and therefore DartEditor happy?

Additional Info: Here are the files illustrating the structure:

```
bash-3.2$ find .
.
./bin
./bin/compile_dart_templates.dart
./bin/docs
./bin/ebisu.ebisu.dart
./bin/packages
./lib
./lib/ebisu.dart
./lib/ebisu_compiler.dart
./lib/ebisu_dart_meta.dart
./lib/ebisu_id.dart
./lib/ebisu_utils.dart
./lib/src
./lib/src/ebisu
./lib/src/ebisu/ebisu.dart
./lib/src/ebisu_compiler
./lib/src/ebisu_compiler/compiler.dart
./lib/src/ebisu_dart_meta
./lib/src/ebisu_dart_meta/meta.dart
./lib/src/ebisu_id
./lib/src/ebisu_id/id.dart
./lib/templates
./lib/templates/dart_meta
./lib/templates/dart_meta/app.tmpl
./lib/templates/dart_meta/class_.tmpl
./lib/templates/dart_meta/enum_.tmpl
./lib/templates/dart_meta/library.tmpl
./lib/templates/dart_meta/member.tmpl
./lib/templates/dart_meta/part.tmpl
./lib/templates/dart_meta/pubspec.tmpl
./lib/templates/dart_meta/script.tmpl
./lib/templates/dart_meta/src
./lib/templates/dart_meta/src/app.dart
./lib/templates/dart_meta/src/class_.dart
./lib/templates/dart_meta/src/enum_.dart
./lib/templates/dart_meta/src/library.dart
./lib/templates/dart_meta/src/member.dart
./lib/templates/dart_meta/src/part.dart
./lib/templates/dart_meta/src/pubspec.dart
./lib/templates/dart_meta/src/script.dart
./lib/templates/dart_meta/src/variable.dart
./lib/templates/dart_meta/variable.tmpl
./lib/templates/dart_meta.dart
./packages
./packages/ebisu
./packages/pathos
./pubspec.lock
./pubspec.yaml
./test
./test/ebisu_functions.dart
./test/packages
bash-3.2$ cat ./pubspec.yaml
name: ebisu
version: 0.0.1
description: >
  A library that supports code generation of the structure Dart (and potentially
  other languages like D) using a fairly declarative aproach.

dependencies:
  pathos:
bash-3.2$ dart bin/ebisu.ebisu.dart 
Done
bash-3.2$ dartdoc --out /tmp/docs/ebisu bin/ebisu.ebisu.dart 
Analyzing libraries...
bin/ebisu.ebisu.dart:3:8: Error: Cannot read "../../../../dart/dart-sdk/packages/ebisu/ebisu.dart" (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2).
import "package:ebisu/ebisu.dart";
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: generation failed: Failed to create mirror system.
bash-3.2$ dartdoc --out /tmp/docs/ebisu --package-root=`pwd`/packages bin/ebisu.ebisu.dart 
Analyzing libraries...
```

Here are the set of my import statements:

```
find . -name \*dart | xargs grep "import \""
./bin/compile_dart_templates.dart:import "dart:io";
./bin/compile_dart_templates.dart:import "package:pathos/path.dart" as path;
./bin/compile_dart_templates.dart:import "package:ebisu/ebisu.dart";
./bin/compile_dart_templates.dart:import "package:ebisu/ebisu_id.dart";
./bin/compile_dart_templates.dart:import "package:ebisu/ebisu_compiler.dart";
./bin/ebisu.ebisu.dart:import "dart:io";
./bin/ebisu.ebisu.dart:import "package:pathos/path.dart" as path;
./bin/ebisu.ebisu.dart:import "package:ebisu/ebisu.dart";
./bin/ebisu.ebisu.dart:import "package:ebisu/ebisu_id.dart";
./bin/ebisu.ebisu.dart:import "package:ebisu/ebisu_dart_meta.dart";
./bin/ebisu.ebisu.dart:import "package:ebisu/ebisu_compiler.dart";
./lib/ebisu.dart:import "dart:io";
./lib/ebisu.dart:import "package:pathos/path.dart" as path;
./lib/ebisu_compiler.dart:import "dart:io";
./lib/ebisu_compiler.dart:import "package:ebisu/ebisu.dart";
./lib/ebisu_compiler.dart:import "package:pathos/path.dart" as path;
./lib/ebisu_dart_meta.dart:import "dart:io";
./lib/ebisu_dart_meta.dart:import "dart:json";
./lib/ebisu_dart_meta.dart:import "package:ebisu/ebisu.dart";
./lib/ebisu_dart_meta.dart:import "package:ebisu/ebisu_id.dart";
./lib/ebisu_dart_meta.dart:import "package:ebisu/ebisu_utils.dart" as EBISU_UTILS;
./lib/ebisu_dart_meta.dart:import "templates/dart_meta.dart" as META;
./lib/ebisu_id.dart:import "dart:io";
./lib/ebisu_id.dart:import "package:ebisu/ebisu.dart";
./lib/ebisu_id.dart:import "package:pathos/path.dart" as path;
./lib/ebisu_id.dart:import "ebisu_utils.dart" as EBISU_UTILS;
./lib/ebisu_utils.dart:import "dart:math";
./lib/src/ebisu_compiler/compiler.dart:import "package:ebisu/ebisu.dart";
./lib/src/ebisu_compiler/compiler.dart:import "package:ebisu/ebisu_dart_meta.dart";
./lib/templates/dart_meta.dart:import "package:ebisu/ebisu.dart";
./lib/templates/dart_meta.dart:import "package:ebisu/ebisu_dart_meta.dart";
./test/ebisu_functions.dart:import "package:ebisu/ebisu.dart";
```

Comment: Not sure about dartdoc problem, but one pointer: use relative imports. You don't need to prefix everything with "package:ebisu/" inside your lib folder.

Comment: Did you try creating a symlink named `packages` in your bin folder, pointing to the "real" packages directory?

Comment: @pravelgj: Relative packages may work, but package should also (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135458/how-to-have-libraries-import-libraries-from-the-same-package). I'm choosing package per amouravski's advice and for consistency. I had issues when accidentally mixing relative and package type imports from within package to same dart file. Is there a benefit to using relative imports?

Comment: @MarioP: Yes the bin/packages points to the real packages as that was required to successfully run the command 'dart bin/ebisu.ebisu.dart'.